# Sql query to fetch value from table in grouping using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help. I need sql query to fetch value from table and group it if duplicate value is present in table.I am explaining my table below.

> db_basic:

```
id     name_id     name       date1              date2

1        60        aaa        2016-10-22       2016-10-26

2        60        aaa                                       

3        62        ccc
```

Here some rows has `date1 and date2` column blank.I have the input like this `$date=2016-10-22`.I need to fetch `name_id and name` value using the condition `$date=2016-10-22` is lies in between `date1 and date2`. Here my condition also if any `name_id` row has `date1 and date2` column has some value that will be fetched with comparing the input date(`$date=2016-10-22`) .If any row has no value for `date1 and date2` column those should fetch without comparing with any input. I am explaining my query below.

```
$sql="select * from db_basic where date1 <='".$date."' and date2 >= '".$date."' and date1 !='' and date2 !='' group by name_id";
```

But using this query i can not get the last row value from the table.My condition is if `date1 and date2` has value it will compare other wise it will fetch the data from database without comparing. Please help me.

Comment: try this $sql="select * from db_basic where date1 <='".$date."' and date2 >= '".$date."' and date1 !='' and date2 !='' group by name_id  union all select * from db_basic where date1 ='' and date2 ='' group by name_id ";

Comment: Can you post this in answer section ?

Comment: first try this if its work as you expected then i will post it as answer

Comment: @JYoThI : Its working .Thank you.

Comment: i posted as answer. if its working mark it with green tick its useful for future user reference @subhra

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `db_basic` WHERE `date1` <='$date' AND `date2` >= '$date' AND `date1` IS NOT NULL AND `date2` IS NOT NULL GROUP by `name_id`;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `UNION ALL`

```
$sql="select * from db_basic where date1 <='".$date."' and date2 >= '".$date."' and date1 !='' and date2 !='' group by name_id union all select * from db_basic where date1 ='' and date2 ='' group by name_id ";
```

Comment: Ok,its working but if i am adding order by its not working.